Nextjs subdomains/multiple sites in one project
In my Nextjs project I want to have different websites for different subdomains. Maybe something like having a folder for each each subdomain in the src/pages folder. For example src/pages/mysubdomain for mysubdomain.mydomain.com. what would work as well is just having multiple pages folders and selecting which on to use at deployment. Setting up multiple projects is not really a solution for me, since I want to reuse components across the different subdomain sites.
I have already searched for solutions, but haven't found anything useful. I have tried using a server.ts file, which didn't work.

If you don't necessarily need your projects to be in src/pages. You can use mono-repos. You can have shared component libraries, configuration, etc., but you can divide the project into sub-projects.
Turbo repo is one such popular choice when it comes to mono-repo: https://turbo.build/repo
